# SQL finding Average for transaction

Tags: sql

so i have a question regarding Average problem. suppose i have 5 transactions, with each transaction having multiple items and each item has their own Quantity Value. I want to search Average Quantity per transaction. Note that in my ERD Design, there are 2 separate tables which are HeaderTransaction and TransactionDetail.

If i use AVG() function, then it will be very weird as i.e.

first transaction:

- 5 eggs
- 2 sausages

Second transaction :

- 3 eggs
- 10 sausages.

AVG will work like (5+2+3+10)/4 what i want is ((5+2)+(3+10))/2

my current solution is

```
SELECT SUM(ItemQuantity)/COUNT (DISTINCT (SalesTransactionId)) as[aveg]
```

i find it a bit rough

Comment: *I want to search Average Quantity per transaction.* `Sum(items_amount)/Count(transactions)`

Comment: i do need the keyword 'DISTINCT' as it will result in different answer

Comment: Are you using both MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server? If not, remove the extraneous tag. The answer may vary depending on the actual DBMS your are using.

Comment: You have a neat solution which I don't think can be improved.

Comment: You're aware that only the divisor is different in  `(5+2+3+10)/4` and `((5+2)+(3+10))/2` ?

Comment: im aware, those parenthesis only serve as indication that i want to sum qty in each transaction and divide with how many transaction happened. AVG() function is wrong in that case

Answer (score 0):

> If i use AVG() function, then it will be very weird

Not if you AVG what you say you want to average, which is the number of items per transaction

```
SELECT AVG(num_of_items_in_transaction) 
FROM
  (SELECT SUM(amount_of_item) as num_of_items_in_transaction FROM detail GROUP BY tran_id)
```

The inner query groups per transaction, and counts the total number of items. The outer query then averages these totals. The point is that because you need to first do an operation group by transaction, then another operation group by something else (the whole dataset) you can't combine the grouping operations into a single step - it has to be multi stage, because you're feeding the output from one stage into the input of another. `SELECT AVG(SUM(amount)) .. GROUP BY ???` - what would you put into the `???` to let MySQL know you wanted the SUM grouping by one thing but the AVG grouping by another? (You can't)

You generally need to do it as a two step reduction if you're not windowing, but that's conceivably a implicit multi-step operation anyway

I don't think there's any need to change what you have (sum of amounts divided by count of transactions), I just wanted to point out why it probably wasn't working as you expected